# Config MongoDB Servers

Tags: mongodb

Following the Oreily Scaling MongoDB book, I saw the following command:

> Let’s say we have three data centers: one in New York, one in San
>   Francisco, and one on the moon. We start up one config server in each
>   center.

```
$ ssh ny-01
ny-01$ mongod
$ ssh sf-01
sf-01$ mongod
$ ssh moon-01
moon-01$ mongod

$ ssh ny-02
```

> ny-01$ mongos --configdb ny-01,sf-01,moon-01 Press Enter, and now all
>   the config servers know about each other. The mongos is like the host
>   of the party that introduces them all to each other.

Question:

Does **ny-01**, **sf-01**, and **moon-01** mean the machine name or machine IP address?

Answer (score 0):

In the book example, hostname. I believe you can use either, but use IPs in order to avoid having to resolve them, and to be sure that any failure is not due to hostname resolution issues.